# Where() throws IDbAsyncEnumerable not implemented

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, async-await

I have an Repository. 
For Unitest I use an Fake-Repository that returns a FakeDbSet (Implementation found on internet) 
with IDbAsyncEnumerable-Implementation.

My Fake-Methode locks like:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> GetAll()
{
var foo=new Foo();
return new FakeDbSet<Foo>() { foo }.AsQueryable();
}
```

So this Code works in UnitTest:

```
Foo[] foo = await MyRepo.GetAll().ToArrayAsync();
```

but this don't

```
Foo[] foo = await MyRepo.GetAll().Where(x=>x.Id==1).ToArrayAsync();
```

Error: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable.

Because the Where-Methode returns IQueryable.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the paragraph from MSDN about your case

**Async Methods when Unit Testing**

Whilst the async methods are only supported when running against an EF query, you may want to use them in your unit test when running against an in-memory test double of a DbSet.

For more details on how to achieve this scenario see the 'Testing with async queries' section of Testing with a Mocking Framework or Testing with your own test doubles.

For detailed information please [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn313107.aspx):